# "My stuff" vs. "Your stuff" in UI texts

Tags: naming, usability, wording

When refering to a users stuff should you use *My* or *Your*, for example:

> My Cart | My Account | My Wishlist

Or

> Your Cart | Your Account | Your Wishlist

I found this [article](http://www.designingsocialinterfaces.com/patterns.wiki/index.php?title=Your_vs._My) that argues for the use of *your*. It says flikr does this. It also says MySpace and MyYahoo are wrong.

I also noticed today that Amazon uses the term *Your*. However, I have heard they are the masters at testing variations and finding the best one, so what you see on their site might be the best variation, or simply something they are currently testing.

I personally like the way *my* looks better, but thats just my opinion.

What do you think? What will hever the better impact on customers? Does it really even matter?

Comment: To an extent, a question better suited for: http://english.stackexchange.com/ *[your, I think]*

Comment: I prefer "Your". Another good site to ask this on may be [UI.stackexchange.com](http://ui.stackexchange.com).

Comment: See [User Profile, My Account, or just Settings?](http://ui.stackexchange.com/q/1328/60) on the UI site.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a UI site, Thanks guys.

Comment: Don't take Amazon as a good example, it's an antiquated site and they've got rather bad usability.

Comment: I saw a great video last night on YourTube :)

Comment: @Developer Art: Maybe it's just that I've got used to it, but I find Amazon to be one of the easier shopping sites.

Comment: Amazon are renowned for their use of A/B testing. If there are two ways of doing things, they will test one and pick the one that converts better, even if the difference in conversion rates is only a few percentiles. If Amazon do something it's because it chimes better with their users.

Comment: Dustin Curtis wrote a good article on this topic: **[Yours vs. Mine](http://dcurt.is/yours-vs-mine)**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use "My" everywhere.

"Yours" creates a psychological barrier between the site and the user, communicating the message that the user is just a user and is only one of many.

Comment: Using "My" also creates the illusion that the object belongs to the user instead of the corporation/business, and people are more likely to take care of their own stuff than others

Comment: @Rachel, that's a brilliant observation!

Comment: This is a great question. At first glance I was in the "your" camp.  But really, if I'm shopping online, I don't want to see _your_ cart, I want to see _my_ cart.  'My' empowers the user by giving them the feeling of ownership.

Comment: Windows uses "my" convention. My Documents. My Pictures...

Comment: Using "My" also makes more sense to distinguish areas populated by user (My Wishlist, My Cart) from others. It is also a brilliant example how a small, nearly meaningless word makes a huge difference for a lot of people.

Answer (score 16):

Keep in mind that *My* or *Your* can be a component of the branding as with MySpace and not contextual as would be *Your Cart* or *My Cart*.

I would ditch both.

> Cart Account Wishlist

*My* and *Your* are an attempt to bring personalization into the product. IMHO it simply adds un-needed fluff and yet another word spread across a product the brain must process.

If we've learned anything from the successful start-ups over the past few years, it's that simplicity wins. Let's not revert back to over personalization and un-needed verbiage.

Comment: I agree, but there are many who like the "My.." syntax. People apparently like fake familiarity.

Comment: They may like the syntax at the infancy of the product...but the value diminishes almost immediately once the user becomes familiar with the product. There is no lasting value.

Comment: I agree, when referring to the links commonly put on the top of the page linking to the cart or account. but when you access the page, I think the heading just "Account" will seem odd.

Comment: How about prefix them all with "The": "The Cart", "The Account", "The Wishlist"? :P

Comment: Such prefixes rarely bear any useful information. They only make sense, when you want to distinguish between "your / our" ... for example "offer".

Comment: Even MS ditched 'My Documents' in favor of 'Documents'.  'My' and 'Your' tend to come across as patronizing, particularly 'My'.

Comment: I hate both with a passion, but 'My' is worse than 'Your' - 'My' almost feels like the site is trying to invade my personal sphere or just plain old lie to me (it's not "My Acme", I don't own the company, don't try to make it look like you are all mine while really all you want is my money).

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, using "Your" is better. An [article on A List Apart says that "Your" is preferable](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/designing-web-registration-forms-for-kids/) especially for children.

An [article on the Yahoo! developer network](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/social/core/yourvmy.html) makes a good point about the issue:

> Labeling stuff with "My" imitates the point of view of the user. It is as if the user has printed out labels and stuck them to various objects: My Lunch, My Desk, My Red Stapler. Except the user hasn't done this; you (the site) did it for them.
>
> Labeling stuff with "Your" instead reinforces the conversational dialogue. It is how another human being might address you when talking about your stuff. Even with MySpace, people say things like "I saw what you put on your MySpace."